# php based webservice for ios app for instant messaging

Tags: php, ios, web-services

Hii folks i am having one question please don't mark this post as spam .I am just beginner in web services and need of a chat application on ios app .

I am  using cake php for web services. i just want to know the keywords i mean how can i search for this topic i am having some keywords like socket and comet to built chat services  .

please guide me just want to know how we can implement this not coding just hint me then i will Google for this .Also please tell me which one would be best because in my app while chat a user can send 10 sec video

Answer (score 1):

Hey as Nishant says  you have two option of `REST` and `SOCKETS` .
But problems arise in both ajax and sockets.
If you want to use sockets than `PHP` is not suitable for that , I suggest to use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) with Node.js or Erlang or Akka with Java or Scala  and else if you want to use REST than you can try `MySQL + PHP + JavaScript`.

I can give you a short rough example of REST with JQuery:-
    var lstmsg; window.onload=loadchat();function loadchat(){$.post('newmsg.php?lstmsg='+lstmsg,'xml',function(xml){/* here will be the code to handel ajax*/}); setTimeout('loadchat()',5000);}

Answer (score 0):

yeah.. if you want to create a chat application than there are two main options, one is `socket programming` and another is `ajax`.....

here is a link for example of `socket programming using php`

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418814/Socket-Programming-in-PHP

but it is little complicate to understand.
I will suggest you to use `ajax` rather than `sockets`..

Comment: Thanks For you suggestion but how can i relate this service with my ios app i mean how will we manage chat history and all

Comment: you should fire this chat webservice every 5-10 seconds using `javascript's timer() function`..
this `webservice` will do both **sending / receiving chat messages + inserting data into database**..
you can use `limit` in your `sql statement` to prevent overload in your server.